# Writing a postcode regex that excludes my own postcode

Tags: regex

I'm currently wanting to write a regular expression that matches a postcode that isn't my own. I thought that I could have done this with negative lookaheads etc but these only look after finding any postcode (including my own!). I also would like this to be in one phrase and without the need for any extra code at all (whether JS, Python etc.)

This is what I currently have (with a changed postcode and which doesn't do the desired job):

```
(?=(my postcode regex)(?!SW1 1AA))
```

And assuming my postcode was SW1 1AA, I would like the following results:

```
We need to go to EC2 2BB from SW1 1AA.   <---MATCH
We need to go to EC2 2BB soon.           <---MATCH
We need to go back to SW1 1AA soon.      <---NO MATCH
```

Could someone please advise as I'm now a bit stumped after also looking at using negatives with ! and ^ too. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `my postcode regex`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify a programming language or REGEX engine, but here's one method using the PCRE regex engine that will work.

Use a negative look-ahead to check for your current postcode.

```
((?!SW1 1AA)(my postcode regex))
```

Here's the simplistic postcode regex I made just to verify the regex.

```
((?!SW1 1AA)([A-Z\d]{3}\s[A-Z\d]{3}))
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lP8iI9/1)

```
We need to go to EC2 2BB from SW1 1AA. <---MATCHES EC2 2BB, but will not match SW1 1AA.
We need to go to EC2 2BB soon.         <---MATCHES EC2 2BB
We need to go back to SW1 1AA soon.    <---NO MATCHES
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, besides that suggested by @Nathan, is to use a negative lookbehind, since you are checking at the end of the match. So, assuming "my postcode regex" is the following: `[A-Z0-9]{3} [A-Z0-9]{3}`, this regexp works for me on all of your test cases:

`([A-Z0-9]{3} [A-Z0-9]{3})(?<!SW1 1AA)`

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/yY4pE9/1)